# cannot retrieve data from localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to save Contacts in localStorage in this react application.

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import AddContact from "./AddContact";
// import ContactCard from './ContactCard'
import ContactList from "./ContactList";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    setContacts([...contacts, contact]);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Saving contacts:", contacts);
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    console.log("Retrieved contacts:", retriveContacts);
    if (retriveContacts) setContacts(retriveContacts);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <AddContact AddContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when i am adding contacts it gets saved to localstorage but whenever i fresh the page localStorage gets emptied.

Answer (score 0):

i worked out when i did this way

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import AddContact from "./AddContact";
// import ContactCard from './ContactCard'
import ContactList from "./ContactList";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    setContacts([...contacts, contact]);
    localStorage.setItem(
      LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY,
      JSON.stringify([...contacts, contact])
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const retriveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (retriveContacts) setContacts(retriveContacts);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <AddContact AddContactHandler={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: nice men, I didn't see you already fixed, gj!!

Answer (score 0):

you can save the contacts in the event and can you load directly the contacts in the use state, something like this

```
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(() => {
    const retrieveContacts = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    return retrieveContacts ? JSON.parse(retrieveContacts) : [];
  });
  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    const newContacts = [...contacts, contact];
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(newContacts));
    setContacts(newContacts);
  };
```

and you can remove the useEffects, those would not necessary and prevents any side effects